# Couldn't resolve host 'connect20.magentocommerce.com'

Tags: extensions

I'm new to magento.
when i want to install an extension i get the following message: 
community/Locale_Mage_community_fr_FR: Couldn't resolve host 'connect20.magentocommerce.com'

How do I resolve this?

Tns

Answer (score 1):

Manually adding the host to your hosts table(connect20.magentocommerce.com 66.211.190.69). Maybe your server firewall denies access to the internet by default.

You can also install modules manually.

Grab the key from Magento Connect and copy/paste it on http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php and install the module by hand.